# Reuse generic type T extending a specific class

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to use an `ArrayList` that contains elements of the type specified by the class.

```
public class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractFoo {

    private ArrayList<T> list =  new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public void add(Comparable e) {
        list.add(e); // The method add(T) in the type ArrayList<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable)
    }
}
```

Why can't I add `e` to `list`? As T definitely extends Comparable, I suppose I can add `e` to `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a class `Teacher` and a class `Student` which both implement `Comparable`. Now if you create a `Foo<Teacher>`, this foo object will contain a list of teachers `ArrayList<Teacher>`. If your code would compile, you now could add a student (because it is comparable) to the teacher list, which is of course not allowed.

You might actually want:

```
@Override
public void add(T e) {
    list.add(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because all `T`s are `Comparable`, but not all `Comparables` are `T`s you cannot add a `Comparable` to a list of `T`.

You can do it by having a `ArrayList<Comparable<T>>` though

```
public class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractFoo {

    private ArrayList<Comparable<T>> list =  new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void add(Comparable e) {
        list.add(e); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works because `Comparable` is a raw type. The add method kind of pollutes the `List<Comparable<T>>` with arbitrary comparables in this case.

Comment: True. It would be better to change the method parameter to `Comparable<T> e`. But I feel that might be out of scope for this question